# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token one element works but other one does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run this code it works fine, but if I add another select box it does not work - actually 'Select Project Team Member Role' does not work at all but 'Select Project Team Member' works really fine.

When I run code for 'Select Project Team Member Role' it gives error 'uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'

I need both select box and when I run both none works. I cant find what is the error; please help me out.

HTML

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
      <tr>  
        <td>
          <select name="projteam[]" id="projmem_id" class="form-control">
            <option> Select Project Team Member</option>
            <?php foreach($this->memdata as $pc){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $pc->id ?>"><?php echo $pc->name ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
         </td> 
        <td>
          <select name="keyrole[]" id="role_id" class="form-control">
            <option> Select Project Team Member Role</option>
            <?php foreach($this->roldata as $mr){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $mr->id ?>"><?php echo $mr->key_role ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
        </td> 
      </tr>  
    </table>  
  </div>  
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    var i=1;  
    $('#add').click(function(){  
      i++;  
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><select name="projteam[]" id="projmem_id" class="form-control"><option> Select Project Team Member</option> <?php foreach($this->memdata as $pc){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $pc->id ?>"><?php echo $pc->name ?></option> <?php } ?> </select></td><td><select name="keyrole[]" id="role_id" class="form-control"><option> Select Project Team Member Role</option> <?php foreach($this->roldata as $mr){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $mr->id ?>"><?php echo $mr->key_role ?></option> <?php } ?> </select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
      $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });  
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: When does the error occur? When the page loads? When you click the `#add` button? When you click a `.btn_remove` button? Or...? If you click the line number for the error message in the console that should show exactly which line the error occurred on.

Comment: when page loads it shows error in console and that add button does not works..thank you

Comment: The JS syntax seems OK, so I would guess the problem is that your embedded PHP is outputting something that creates invalid JS, leading to the token error. Please use your browser's "View Page Source" option to get the actual JS that is sent to the browser, and add that to your question.

Comment: You need `.clone()` function as per your requirement, and then `append` the delete button to the cloned content before appending the cloned copy.

Answer (score 1):

The html you have written looks fine but not the JavaScript. Because the PHP piece in the click event will return the html before the event occured. Might be good suggestion to keep your select ready and hidden. Add style='display:none'.
And in the add click event just show them $('#projmem_id').Show(). This way you can keep a clear distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an ajax request to load the content of your option tags, like Srikant Sahu said, the php content is returned before the event occurs.. Here an example of an Ajax Request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#yourid').click(function (event) {
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yourfile.php',
            data: '',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {   
                //create the new select
            }
        });      
     });
});
```